# How to tune cratedb to get 40000 inserts per second as mentioned in official website

Tags: crate

I am benchmarking cratedb with each record having 40 columns and record size varies between 300bytes to 1kb.

I am able to get only 500 inserts per second on single thread.

Using cratedb 1.0.1 with python client.
Machine having 16 CPUs and 32GB RAM.

Please help how can I increase the performance. And on what conditions we get 40,000 inserts per second mentioned in official website.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

40k inserts a second are doable with CrateDB and should not be a huge problem. However, in a single thread the performance is probably lower and depending on response times. If possible, it's recommended to use a multithreaded insert procedure (or at least asynchronous), since CrateDB can handle quite a few concurrent connections. The 40k were achieved with more than a single thread issuing bulk requests.

So the performance issue you are experiencing can have a few causes:

- Your machine doesn't have an SSD (SSDs are crucial for the best performance)
- The table's shard count is too high/too low
- The `CRATE_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is not set correctly
- Your bulk size could be higher

Can you check all of those?

Cheers, Claus